# Different html class every 2 item

Tags: php, algorithm, foreach

In php I try to do this :

```
<div class="left"> some text </div>
<div class="left"> some text </div>
<div class="right"> some text </div>
<div class="right"> some text </div>
<div class="left"> some text </div>
<div class="left"> some text </div>
<div class="right"> some text </div>
<div class="right"> some text </div>
.
.
.
```

I need different class every 2 items to have different html design.

Comment: Could you provide more code or a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try  this,

```
  $arrayX = array("left","right");
    $i = 4;
    while($i<100){
        if($i%4<2){
            echo '<div class="'.$arrayX[0].'"> some text </div>';
        }else{
            echo '<div class="'.$arrayX[1].'"> some text </div>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: produce 
<div class="0"> some text </div>
<div class="1"> some text </div>
<div class="0"> some text </div>
<div class="1"> some text </div>

Comment: Yes it works ! Perfect I use your solution, it's more elegant than others ! Thank you hurricane

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this CSS instead.

```css
div:nth-child(4n+1), 
div:nth-child(4n+2) 
{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a foreach loop that goes through all the 'some text' entries. You could add a counter and then do some simple logic.

```
$yourtexts = array("some text","some text","some text","some text","some text","some text","some text","some text","some text");

$i=0; // counter
foreach ($yourtexts as $sometext) {
    print ($i<2) ? '<div class="left">' : '<div class="right">'; // $i<2 go left else go right
    print "$sometext</div>";
    $i++; // count
    if ($i>3) { $i=0; } // reset to zero.
}
```